# Edit xml config with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a line in my config file (.exe.config)

```
 <appSettings configSource="Configuration\local.config" />
```

And I need use a batch file to change it to

```
 <appSettings configSource="Configuration\production.config" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be very brittle and prone to error, but if you still want to do it, go ahead:

1. We need delayed expansion

   ```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   ```
2. Iterate over the lines in the file

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.exe.config) do (
   ```
3. Store the line

   ```
     set "Line=%%L"
   ```
4. Do the replacement

   ```
     set "Line=!Line:Configuration\local.config=Configuration\production.config!"
   ```
5. Output the line again

   ```
     echo !Line!
   )
   ```

Comment: I chose to use nAnt and xmlpoke instead. Thanks though!